# How can one explain that $(-1) (-1) = 1$

Tags: algebra

How could one explain that $(-1)(-1) = 1$?

I am trying to avoid arbitrary rules. I suggested to my student to think of it as a reflexion around the 0. putting emphasis on the idea that if you reflect twice you get to the point where you started.

This is not so clear to his mind. So I ask for other approaches on the subject.

Comment: There is a closely related question http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/how-to-explain-that-a-negative-number-multiplied-by-a-negative-number-is-a-posit